# Docker build not installing dependencies

Tags: python, docker, pip

I'm trying to build a Docker image with some python packages I need.

Here is the Dockerfile I'm using :

```
FROM oraclelinux:7.8

COPY ./fetch_session_iptv.py /opt/
COPY ./conf/fetch_session_iptv.conf /opt/conf/
#COPY ./conf/certs/* /opt/conf/certs/
COPY ./logs /opt/logs


RUN yum install -y \
    https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64.rpm \
    https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64.rpm \
    https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm

COPY ./python_requirements/elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
COPY ./python_requirements/certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
COPY ./python_requirements/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
COPY ./python_requirements/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl .

RUN pip3 install \
    certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl \
    urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl \
    elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl \
    pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl 

#CMD ["/bin/bash"]

CMD [ "python", "/opt/fetch_session_iptv.py" ]
```

It appears to be installing all dependencies on build :

```
Step 1/11 : FROM oraclelinux:7.8
7.8: Pulling from library/oraclelinux
50ab38810635: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:8d64add00f3b006bf2aae76e26100a334de153b43421671b52389c89e2bf0ba4
Status: Downloaded newer image for oraclelinux:7.8
 ---> d788eca028a0
Step 2/11 : COPY ./fetch_session_iptv.py /opt/
 ---> 52301bdc1114
Step 3/11 : COPY ./conf/fetch_session_iptv.conf /opt/conf/
 ---> d001bf5959fe
Step 4/11 : COPY ./logs /opt/logs
 ---> c4806eb7cfff
Step 5/11 : RUN yum install -y  https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64.rpm https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64.rpm  https://yum.oracle.com/repo/OracleLinux/OL7/developer/x86_64/getPackage/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm
 ---> Running in 3dd09805d581
Loaded plugins: ovl, ulninfo
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-iRz8qd/oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64.rpm: oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-iRz8qd/oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-iRz8qd/python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64.rpm: python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-iRz8qd/python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-iRz8qd/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm: python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-iRz8qd/python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package oracle-instantclient18.3-basic.x86_64 0:18.3.0.0.0-2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libaio for package: oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64
---> Package python36-cx_Oracle.x86_64 0:7.0-1.0.2.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python(abi) = 3.6 for package: python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpython3.6m.so.1.0()(64bit) for package: python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
---> Package python36-pytz.noarch 0:2016.10-2.0.1.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libaio.x86_64 0:0.3.109-13.el7 will be installed
---> Package python3.x86_64 0:3.6.8-13.0.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: python3-pip for package: python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: python3-setuptools for package: python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64
---> Package python3-libs.x86_64 0:3.6.8-13.0.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libtirpc.so.1()(64bit) for package: python3-libs-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtirpc.x86_64 0:0.2.4-0.16.el7 will be installed
---> Package python3-pip.noarch 0:9.0.3-7.el7_8 will be installed
---> Package python3-setuptools.noarch 0:39.2.0-10.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
 Package                        Arch   Version           Repository        Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 oracle-instantclient18.3-basic x86_64 18.3.0.0.0-2      /oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64
                                                                          220 M
 python36-cx_Oracle             x86_64 7.0-1.0.2.el7     /python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64
                                                                          1.3 M
 python36-pytz                  noarch 2016.10-2.0.1.el7 /python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch
                                                                          919 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libaio                         x86_64 0.3.109-13.el7    ol7_latest        24 k
 libtirpc                       x86_64 0.2.4-0.16.el7    ol7_latest        89 k
 python3                        x86_64 3.6.8-13.0.1.el7  ol7_latest        69 k
 python3-libs                   x86_64 3.6.8-13.0.1.el7  ol7_latest       7.0 M
 python3-pip                    noarch 9.0.3-7.el7_8     ol7_latest       1.8 M
 python3-setuptools             noarch 39.2.0-10.el7     ol7_latest       628 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  3 Packages (+6 Dependent packages)

Total size: 232 M
Total download size: 9.5 M
Installed size: 270 M
Downloading packages:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                              1.4 MB/s | 9.5 MB  00:06     
Running transaction check
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded
Running transaction
  Installing : libaio-0.3.109-13.el7.x86_64                                 1/9 
  Installing : oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64           2/9 
  Installing : libtirpc-0.2.4-0.16.el7.x86_64                               3/9 
  Installing : python3-libs-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64                         4/9 
  Installing : python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch                      5/9 
  Installing : python3-pip-9.0.3-7.el7_8.noarch                             6/9 
  Installing : python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64                              7/9 
  Installing : python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64                      8/9 
  Installing : python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch                       9/9 
  Verifying  : python3-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64                              1/9 
  Verifying  : libtirpc-0.2.4-0.16.el7.x86_64                               2/9 
  Verifying  : python36-cx_Oracle-7.0-1.0.2.el7.x86_64                      3/9 
  Verifying  : python3-libs-3.6.8-13.0.1.el7.x86_64                         4/9 
  Verifying  : oracle-instantclient18.3-basic-18.3.0.0.0-2.x86_64           5/9 
  Verifying  : python3-setuptools-39.2.0-10.el7.noarch                      6/9 
  Verifying  : libaio-0.3.109-13.el7.x86_64                                 7/9 
  Verifying  : python36-pytz-2016.10-2.0.1.el7.noarch                       8/9 
  Verifying  : python3-pip-9.0.3-7.el7_8.noarch                             9/9 

Installed:
  oracle-instantclient18.3-basic.x86_64 0:18.3.0.0.0-2                          
  python36-cx_Oracle.x86_64 0:7.0-1.0.2.el7                                     
  python36-pytz.noarch 0:2016.10-2.0.1.el7                                      

Dependency Installed:
  libaio.x86_64 0:0.3.109-13.el7      libtirpc.x86_64 0:0.2.4-0.16.el7          
  python3.x86_64 0:3.6.8-13.0.1.el7   python3-libs.x86_64 0:3.6.8-13.0.1.el7    
  python3-pip.noarch 0:9.0.3-7.el7_8  python3-setuptools.noarch 0:39.2.0-10.el7 

Complete!
Removing intermediate container 3dd09805d581
 ---> c71c9b3eafd9
Step 6/11 : COPY ./python_requirements/elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
 ---> e817f2eea76a
Step 7/11 : COPY ./python_requirements/certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
 ---> 5271764a4e78
Step 8/11 : COPY ./python_requirements/urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
 ---> 903b4e977f97
Step 9/11 : COPY ./python_requirements/pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl .
 ---> 9fe163a90794
Step 10/11 : RUN pip3 install   certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl     urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl     elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl    pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
 ---> Running in f5fa17eedd5c
WARNING: Running pip install with root privileges is generally not a good idea. Try `pip3 install --user` instead.
Processing /certifi-2020.4.5.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /urllib3-1.25.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /elasticsearch-7.8.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing /pytz-2019.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: certifi, urllib3, elasticsearch, pytz
Successfully installed certifi-2020.4.5.2 elasticsearch-7.8.0 pytz-2019.3 urllib3-1.25.9
Removing intermediate container f5fa17eedd5c
 ---> acf68ab49e26
Step 11/11 : CMD [ "python", "/opt/fetch_session_iptv.py" ]
 ---> Running in 94cd8c49a1a5
Removing intermediate container 94cd8c49a1a5
 ---> bcb331fc7575
Successfully built bcb331fc7575
Successfully tagged kansas-fetch:1.4-SNAPSHOT
```

But then when I try to run the docker image I get the following error message :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/fetch_session_iptv.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pytz
ImportError: No module named pytz
```

I'm new to Docker so I guess I must be doing something wrong, but I can't find what exactly.

Comment: try "python3" in CMD instead. Most distros still have Python 2 as the default Python

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Can't believe it was such a simple error